# @NamedQueries Don't Work JPA Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

I have a problem with namedQuery, the problem is that at a focuslost of one of my JTextfields i have a code for a search as follows:

```
     private List<Condutor> condutor;
private void condutorIdFieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                          

    Query condByCod = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Condutor.findByCondutorId");
    condByCod.setParameter("condutorId", Integer.parseInt(condutorIdField.getText()));
    condutor = condByCod.getResultList();
    infracaoNomeMotField.setText((String) condutor.get(1).getCondutorNome());
}
```

My Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "condutor", catalog = "infracoes", schema = "")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Condutor.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Condutor c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Condutor.findByCondutorId",
query = "SELECT c FROM Condutor c WHERE c.condutorId = :condutorId"),
```

Exception, i have updated to the full message:

```
    [EL Info]: 2015-01-20 21:38:41.404--ServerSession(658738084)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-01-20 21:38:42.813--ServerSession(658738084)--file:/home/rlima/NetBeansProjects/Infracoes2/build/classes/_infracoes?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNullPU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2015-01-20 21:38:58.106--UnitOfWork(1877058643)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'condutor_infracao_id' cannot be null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'condutor_infracao_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO infracoes.condutor_infracao (condutor_infracao_id, condutor_id, disposicao_id, empresa_id, infracao_cobrado_respons, infracao_comentario, infracao_data, infracao_data_pg, infracao_desc_premio, infracao_dt_condutor, infracao_hora, infracao_id, infracao_nome_mot, infracao_num_auto, infracao_num_frota, infracao_tipo, infracao_valor, infracao_valor_pago, linha_id, local_id, modelo_id, orgao_id, perimetro_id, pessoa_id, respons_id, servico_id, setor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [27 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Bean.CondutorInfracao[ condutorInfracaoId=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:461)
    at View.CondutorInfracaoView.condutorIdFieldFocusLost(CondutorInfracaoView.java:725)
    at View.CondutorInfracaoView.access$900(CondutorInfracaoView.java:24)
    at View.CondutorInfracaoView$FormListener.focusLost(CondutorInfracaoView.java:668)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:230)
    at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Component.java:6408)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6272)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1887)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:947)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:621)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4742)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
Call: INSERT INTO infracoes.condutor_infracao (condutor_infracao_id, condutor_id, disposicao_id, empresa_id, infracao_cobrado_respons, infracao_comentario, infracao_data, infracao_data_pg, infracao_desc_premio, infracao_dt_condutor, infracao_hora, infracao_id, infracao_nome_mot, infracao_num_auto, infracao_num_frota, infracao_tipo, infracao_valor, infracao_valor_pago, linha_id, local_id, modelo_id, orgao_id, perimetro_id, pessoa_id, respons_id, servico_id, setor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    bind => [27 parameters bound]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Bean.CondutorInfracao[ condutorInfracaoId=null ])
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'condutor_infracao_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO infracoes.condutor_infracao (condutor_infracao_id, condutor_id, disposicao_id, empresa_id, infracao_cobrado_respons, infracao_comentario, infracao_data, infracao_data_pg, infracao_desc_premio, infracao_dt_condutor, infracao_hora, infracao_id, infracao_nome_mot, infracao_num_auto, infracao_num_frota, infracao_tipo, infracao_valor, infracao_valor_pago, linha_id, local_id, modelo_id, orgao_id, perimetro_id, pessoa_id, respons_id, servico_id, setor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [27 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Bean.CondutorInfracao[ condutorInfracaoId=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:863)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'condutor_infracao_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 67 more
```

Its here, complete log.

Comment: Looks liek the erros is not happening in the select query, but in an insert

Comment: Yes it looks, but this erros happens when i just do "focus lost"...not even click insert button....

Comment: The full stack trace of the PersistenceException, including all 'Caused by' parts, would be useful.

Comment: I figured out something that is: I'm using master detail forms, so, if i delete all the components like JTextfields, tables...all that and place new ones ( this time manually) the query woks fine. But then i loose all the work that was done(the form with the mastertable, the JTextfields all connected to the mastertable). So, how to deal with this, or what have i done wrong?Yet, why is this happenning?

Comment: There is no use of NamedQuery there. It is a flush that causes an INSERT. All is in the stack trace. No user interface operation is relevant

Comment: You are right, i placed            "entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);  "  right before the code in the focuslost event, and it worked fine. The question now is how do i do this  in a proper way?